# Cannot load .pyd module in Python

Tags: python, c, dll, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a workflow in Jupyter that uses some C code which has already been compiled to a `.so` file (for Linux, where everything works fine) and a `.pyd` file (for Windows, which I am using). The `import` tree is a little complicated, so bear with me. The error message hopefully explains it:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cabd8b5ab266> in <module>
     12 import plotly.graph_objects as go
     13 
---> 14 from lase_analysis import load_lasefile, load_timeseries

C:/Users/Owner/.../v2\lase_analysis\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from .spectrum import Spectrum
      3 from .threshold import Threshold
----> 4 from .lasemap import LaseMap
      5 from .laseseries import LaseSeries
      6 from .readermatl import ReaderMATL

C:/Users/Owner/.../v2\lase_analysis\lasemap.py in <module>
     14 from .filelase import FileLase
     15 from .spectrum import Spectrum, PeakFitOpt
---> 16 from .utils.c_funcs import clst_dist
     17 
     18 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing c_funcs: The specified module could not be found.
```

Basically, in the Jupyter session, I am importing `__init__.py` from the folder `lase_analysis` (the first arrow in the error message), which imports a class `LaseMap` from the file `lasemap.py`. Then, this `lasemap.py` file tries to open a C function `clst_dist` from the file `c_funcs.pyd`, which is located in a folder called `utils` which is in this same folder `lase_analysis` that all of the previously mentioned Python files are located in. However, I still get the error that the `.dll` file (which should be equivalent to a `.pyd` file here) cannot be found.

Any help would be appreciated, and my apologies if this was a bit hard to follow.